# zend router ini file add regex exceptions in rule

Tags: regex, zend-framework, routes

I have three routers as shown below. I want to add an exception to the first router so that it would not process the other two routers. I tried to an add exception state in the first router but it did not work.
`routes.frontindex.route = "/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)!link !template ?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?"`

Any idea where I am wrong?

```
; frontindex routes starts here
routes.frontindex.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.frontindex.route = "/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?"
routes.frontindex.defaults.module = frontManagement
routes.frontindex.defaults.controller = Index
routes.frontindex.map.page = 1
routes.frontindex.map.siteid = 2
; frontindex routes stops here


; templateStyles routes starts here
routes.templatestyle2.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.templatestyle2.route = "template/templatestyle/(add|test)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?"
;routes.templatestyle2.defaults.module = templateManagement
;routes.templatestyle2.defaults.controller = Template-style
;routes.templatestyle2.map.action = 1
;routes.templatestyle2.map.key = 2
;routes.templatestyle2.map.id = 2
; templateStyles routes stops here

; link routes starts here
    routes.link.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
    routes.link.route = "link/link/(add|test)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?"
    ;routes.link.defaults.module = linkManagement
    ;routes.link.defaults.controller = link-style
    ;routes.link.map.action = 1
    ;routes.link.map.key = 2
    ;routes.link.map.id = 2
    ; linkroutes stops here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

- add first a cath-all default route which is a **Zend_Controller_Router_Route** and not a **Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex**. Add a [requirement](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard.variable-requirements) on this route with a regexp that would exclude matching cases for the other routes.

In a .ini file the syntax is:

```
routes.frontindex.reqs.something="my-regexp-catching-valid-case-for-this-default-not-regexp-route"
```

Comment: did not understand anything above. could you please explain how this is going to fit in my above code?

Comment: In the 1st route (which shoudl not be a regexp one) map the first word ('template', 'link' or 'something') in a variable of the route and add a requirement on that word (not 'template' or 'link'), see the link on requirement.